# Random walk in two dimensions

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains, random-walk

I'm struggling to solve the following problem for my project:

Given the set of points $(i,j)$ where $i=1,2,3,...,N+1$ and $j=0,1$. Find the probability of getting to the point $(N+1,1)$ from the point $(1,0)$, and from $(2,1)$. Given that the probability to move right is $r$, left is $l$ and up or down is $k$. (so from $j=1$ you can move only down and from $j=0$ only up)

Condition: point $(1,1)$ is absorbing, in other words the probability of getting from $(1,1)$ to $(N+1,1)$ is zero.

I already have some particular solutions for $N=1,2,3,4,..$, but the purpose is to obtain a solution in terms of $r, l, k, N$. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: I guess you mean that you can only move down when $j=1$ and only move up when $j=0$.  Is that right?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The whole thing is on lines $y=0$ and $y=1$.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include that information in the question.  We want questions to be self-contained, so that people don't need to read the comments to understand what you're asking.  Also, I suggest you clarify what type of answer you're looking for.  How will you use it?  What properties do you need it to satisfy, for it to be useful to you?

Comment: Possibly related: https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/119105/755

Comment: Added that. I already specified the answer I need. The question is self-contained.

Answer (score 1):

Designate the allowed points in a binary way:
 - $0,2,4, \cdots,2N$, for the points $(i,0)$;
 - $1,3,5, \cdots,2N+1$, for the points $(i,1)$.
that is

[image: Path_Stripe_2]

Then we may construct a Markov process, whose
transition matrix will be as sketched below.

[image: Path_Stripe_1]

Only that, from your description, I did not catch exactly what are the movement probabilities at the extreme points.

Comment: According to your table, you go from 0 to 2 with probability $r$, because it's on the right. From $2N$ to $2N-2$ with probability $l$, and from $2N+1$ to $2N+1$ is $1$ because the process will arrive to it's destination.

Comment: I defined the conditions as rigorously as I could. But to put it more visual and in words: from the top-left corner, you cannot go anywhere. From the bottom-left, you can only go right. From the bottom-right you can go up (and you arrive at the destination) or you can go left. The top-right is the destination. Also from the point on the right from the top-left point you can go only down or right.

Comment: I need to find an expression in terms of $l,r,k,N$ that gives the probability to arrive at the top-right from the bottom-left and another one to arrive to the same destination from the point on the right from top-left.

Comment: So, from "top-left c." = $1$ only to $1$, from "bottom-left c. = $0$ only right, i.e. only to $2$ (and not also to $1$ ?), etc.  Then pls. complete the matrix above according to your conditions, taking note that **in each row the sum of prob. shall be 1**

Comment: int the row for point 3 there will be just $k$ and $r$, but $k+r$ is not $1$.

Comment: If we have 4 points on top (1,3,5,7) and the bottom (0,2,4,6).If you need the rows to sum to 1 it can be done artificially. Yes from 0 you can't go to the left or up, but it can be assigned that from 0 yo go to 1 with probability (l+k), you end up at 1 and you cannot escape and get to 7. Same with point 6, it cannot go to right, but you can assign it that it goes to 1 and vanish.

$\left(\begin{array}{rrrrrrrr}0&\ell + k&r&0&0&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0&0&0&0&0\\\ell&0&0&k&r&0&0&0\\0&\ell&k&0&0&r&0&0\\0&0&\ell&0&0&k&r&0\\0&0&0&\ell&k&0&0&r\\0&r&0&0&\ell&0&0&k\\0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1\\\end{array}\right)$

Comment: Maybe there is some confusion concerning the binary labeling: pls. refer to the added sketch to fill the transition matrix with the proper probabilities. Do you know something about Markov process?

Comment: I understood correctly your notation, and I provided an example for $N=3$. That's how a transition matrix would look like the labeling of each column and row is from $0$ to $7$.

Comment: I also specify how we can adjust the matrix to be stochastic (each row sums to one) and also to meet the boundary conditions of the problem. Yes, I'm familiar with Markov processes, it would help if you say what is the way that you suggest as an attempt to solve the problem. If you suggest looking at the different powers of the transition matrix through decomposition, I tried that way but the level of complexity of expressions for eigenvalues for high $N$ is extreme and in terms of $N$ is unbearable. Please tell me what is the plan you suggest.

Comment: How is it , in the example you gave in the comment, that you can go from 6 to 1, with probability $r$ (right)? Do you allow circular movement ?

Comment: The process will go to $1$ with probability $r$ and stop there because there is no return from $1$.