# Combinatorics problem about counting ternary strings

Tags: combinatorics

Here is a problem.

Count how many strings of length $n=1,2,3,4,..$ with three possible states for each position $p$, $q$ or $k$ satisfy the following:

$(1)$ the number of $k$'s in each string is always even and the number of $p$'s is equal to the number of $q$'s plus some constant of the same parity with $n$.

$(2)$ each string can start with "$p$" or "$k,p$" ($k$ followed by $p$) and end with either "$p$" or "$p,k$" (ending in $k$ that is preceded by $p$).

$(3)$ if the total number of $k$'s up to any position es even (zero is even) then after that position and to the next $k$ the number of $q$ is strictly less then the number of $p$'s. In another case, it can be less or equal.

I need to provide an answer in the form of a sum in terms of the number of $q$'s.

---

Here are some xamples:

for n=3: $\{p,p,p\}$, $\{k,p,k\}$

for n=4: $\{p,p,p,p\}$, $\{p,k,p,k\}$, $\{p,k,k,p\}$ $\{k,p,k,p\}$,$\{k,p,p,k\}$

for n=5: $\{p,p,p,p,p\}$, $\{p,k,k,p,p\}$, $\{p,p,k,k,p\}$,$\{p,p,q,p,p\}$,$\{p,p,k,p,k\}$,$\{p,k,p,p,k\}$,$\{k,p,p,p,k\}$,$\{k,p,k,p,p\}$,$\{k,p,p,k,p\}$

Comment: It would help if you put into the question the allowed sequences for $n=1,2,3,4,5$.

Comment: Ok, added that.

Comment: I think @almagest meant to provide examples. For example as far as I understood for $n=1$ the only possible string is $[p]$ by the second rule right ? Same for $n=2$ the only sequence is $[p,p]$. Can you provide those for $n=3,4,5$ ?

Comment: What is the source of this problem?  It looks like a programming challenge.

Comment: It's not a programming challenge it arises naturally from a pure-math problem I 'm trying to solve here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3495063/random-walk-in-two-dimensions

Comment: Added examples. Thank you.

Comment: Why not $pkkp$ for $n=4$? Does (3) mean the number of $q$s after the first one must be strictly less than the number of $p$'s, so that the first $k$ must be followed by a $p$? But you allow $ppkkp$ for $n=5$.

Comment: @almagest you are right, $pkkp$ is allowed for four. The string $ppkkp$ is OK for $n=5$ because the number of $p$'s is bigger the number of $q$'s by 3, which has the same parity with $n=5$ by (1) rule, which does not contradict the (3) because after the first $k$ there is less $q$'s than $p$.

Comment: checked again the examples. They are complete.